# LINQ Query Speed Issues use .Any

Tags: c#, sql, performance, linq

I have a query that pulls out about 26k records from the db.

```
var securityEEs = GlobalVariables.SecurityEmployees;
// get all ees for client
var ees = _dbContext.Employees.Where(emp => emp.CompanyID == GlobalVariables.CompanyID && emp.ClientID == GlobalVariables.Client).Select(e => new { e.EmployeeID, e.FirstName, e.LastName }).ToList();
//now filter list down to only include viewable employees
ees = ees.Where(emp => securityEEs.Any(eid => eid == emp.EmployeeID)).ToList();
```

When it gets to the filter to only include viewable employees I feel like the `.Any` is taking a significantly long amount of time. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Did you do any debugging on SQL level? LINQ2SQL (in this case looking like some EntityFramework) is generating SQL. NOTHING saves you from not using proper indices on the database, particulkarly when you force a subquery IF EXISTS (which you do). LINQ is not a magic want - it is a tool. You are supposed to do your homework with it - have a proper database and provide US with proper  detauls. For the performance, LINQ is quite irrelevant, all dependso n the SQL generated in this case.

Comment: Don't pull down a ton of data you don't need from the DB and then filter it by doing tons of linear searches on a collection, both of which are things that are very slow.  Actually query just the right records from the DB.

Comment: I think the bigger issue would be with how ees is created first. Make sure you have the proper indexes. After you call .ToList (Really anything that changes a IQueryable to an IEnumerable or something else) you are calling execute to the server.

Comment: In other words, after .ToList you are doing inmemory operations, which would be fast.

Comment: How many items there is in `securityEEs`?

Comment: 16k are in the securityEEs

Comment: Remove the `ToList()` from `ees` initialization.